# Registering for local notification returns UIUserNotificationTypeNone after user chooses "Allow" on iOS9

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilocalnotification, xcode7, ios9

This has worked in iOS 8 and prior, so it may be a bug in iOS 9 beta - or it's a changed behaviour.

After asking the user for permission to send local notifications -

```
        NSSet *categories = ...;
        UIUserNotificationType notificationTypes = UIUserNotificationTypeBadge | UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert;
        UIUserNotificationSettings *notificationSettings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:notificationTypes categories:categories];

        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:notificationSettings];
```

and user chooses "Allow", `application:didRegisterUserNotificationSettings:` is called with `[notificationSettings types] == UIUserNotificationTypeNone`.

However, the next time I run `registerUserNotificationSettings` it will be called with the correct permission types.

Apple's reference doesn't say anything that may indicate this is intended, so it may be a bug.

Anyone knows what's the problem or how to work around it?

Answer (score 1):

You can workaround this behaviour (which kinda looks like a bug) by checking `[application currentUserNotificationSettings]` in `application:didRegisterUserNotificationSettings:` instead

Answer (score -1):

Just found that Apple have modified their `didRegisterUserNotificationSettings` method

From

```
 - (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterUserNotificationSettings:(UIUserNotificationSettings *)notificationSettings
```

To

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication * nonnull)application didRegisterUserNotificationSettings:(UIUserNotificationSettings * nonnull)notificationSettings
```

Don't know wether this will resolve issue but you can try.

Comment: It's not that, the method is called so it's the correct one. Plus I don't see `nonnull` on my Xcode...